# How many simultaneous requests can I send to ElasticSearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to send multiple bulk operation requests to ElasticSearch cluster, and I come across this issue `EsRejectedExecutionException[rejected execution (queue capacity 50) on org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction`

I have a cluster of 4 ElasticSearch instances (version 1.3.4), when I sent this request to get the number of its bulk operation thread pool size:

```
GET /_cat/thread_pool?v&h=host,bulk.active,bulk.queueSize
```

I got

```
host    bulk.active bulk.queueSize
1D4HPY1           0             50 
1D4HPY2           0             50
1D4HPY3           0             50 
1D4HPY4           0             50
```

So how many simultaneous bulk operation requests I can send to that cluster? `50 or 200`?

Comment: I suggest that you use a Load tester such as Tsung to know how much requests your cluster can handle

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest having a look at [this section from the documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html).

Also, you need to be more specific when you say "simultaneous requests that you can send" because, as you see in the page above, there are various thread pools that handle various jobs. You give an example in your post for "bulk" operations.

In my opinion, the correct request for "bulk" to see the number of simultaneous running threads (as per [this piece of documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-thread-pool.html)) is `GET /_cat/thread_pool?v&h=host,bulk.queueSize,bulk.min,bulk.max`. So, you have `bulk.max` active threads allowed in the thread pool with a `bulk.queueSize` number of tasks in the queue for it. When a request comes in and there are no threads to handle it, the request is put in queue to wait.

Comment: Andrei: I actually send bulk operations to ElasticSearch, and got this error EsRejectedExecutionException[rejected execution (queue capacity 50) on org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1@5bf40589];
So I decide to check its capacity first then send the bulk operation request.
So in my case, how many bulk request I can make to the cluster? 50 or 200?

Comment: This is more complicated than this. A bulk request will be split into smaller chunks, specific to each shard (operations that should go into that specific shard) and a node can hold more than one shard. So, even if you make a request to one node, that request is split into separate chunks and each node that holds a shard involved in the _bulk will queue 0, 1 or more smaller requests in the _bulk thread pool. For example, if you have on one node 5 shards and each has operations to perform from the initial _bulk operation then in the thread pool queue you will have +5 occupied "slots".

Comment: Actually I figured out the equation for my case:
active + queue < max + queueSize
Instead greedily send bulk operations to cluster, I gently check first and wait before sending. It ends up I don't miss anything

Thanks for telling me about bulk.max